# How to create ipa file in flutter for testing purpose?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, flutter, ipa, diawi

I am working in flutter and i want to create an ipa file for testing purpose.
Is there any way to create ipa directly from android studio terminal? If there,what are the steps to follow in that.
Also i have created through diawi, but showing error in installing the app through the url provided by diawi.

Please give me a step by step procedure to follow.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/cd

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For making a build for iOS, you need to run following command from android studio terminal:

```
flutter build ios --release
```

Now you have to make build from Xcode by configuring correct certificates and provisioning profiles:

```
Go to Xcode > Select Generic Device in Devices Pan
Then from the Window menu Choose Product > Archive
```

EDIT: How to get the build?

After clicking on archive, It will take some time to get binaries bind into build and after that it will give you some options to add preferable provisioning profiles. After completing all the process you get an option to download build. Just choose your preferred location to download and it will be downloaded. Open the downloaded folder and get your ipa.

Comment: After archive what to do?

Comment: After clicking on achieve, It will take some time to get binaries bind into build and after that it will give you some options to add preferable provisioning profiles. After completing all the process you get an option to download build. Just choose your preferred location to download and it will be downloaded. Open the downloaded folder and get your ipa.

Comment: The last comment should be part of your answer :)

Comment: I did not get the option to download the build... where might it be ?

Comment: @Bliv_Dev I have updated the answer, you may check.

Comment: After archive I can't see the option to download. Im using Xcode 12.5

Comment: Thanks, it works. And after archive, who want to download the ipa, should choose the option: export ad hoc.

Comment: Once the application is installed on the device, for how long will it stay on iphone?

Answer (score 8):

None of the above worked for me so this is what I did:

1. Run:
   `flutter build ios --release`
2. Go to Xcode -> select Any iOS Device
3. Select product -> archive
4. Once done, In the popup dialog, select distribute then select Adhoc (Install on designated devices) then click next
5. On the next page, select none for app thinning then click next
6. Select automatically manage signing then click next or manually manage signing if you want to change the provisioning profile then, click next
7. Click export, then select the desired location you want to save the ipa then click export.
8. Once done, where you exported to should have the ipa. You can upload this ipa to firebase app distribution or where neccessary.

Comment: Hey, could you explain step 3 a bit more? I'm searching for something like "product", but can't find anything. The only thing I found is "Products" inside the Project Navigator, but this doesn't list "archive"

Comment: Sure, you will find the "Product" in the menu bar at the top in when you launch Xcode

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to do that

**1. Using build ipa**

```
 flutter build ipa --export-options-plist="---/build/ios/archive/ProjectName.xcarchive/Info.plist" // Add abosulte path(Exact location of file in disk)
```

**2. Using build ios**

1. Run `flutter build ios` (it will generate `AppName.app` file)
2. Find above generated file in project structure `build/ios/iphoneos/AppName.app`(go to this location through finder)

3. Copy `AppName.app` and create a `ProjectName` folder on desktop or any location and paste `AppName.app` inside the newly created folder.
4. Compress the `ProjectName` folder(It will look like `ProjectName.zip`)
5. Finally, Rename `ProjectName.zip` to `ProjectName.ipa` and use this .ipa

Sometimes, the first may not work due to certification issues, but the second should work always.

Comment: I get "There's been an error parsing your app's info.plist. Ensure you are uploading a valid IPA and try again." when trying to upload that ipa file to Firebase App Distribution.

Comment: this doesn't work for me

Comment: I am getting error There's been an error parsing your app's info.plist. Ensure you are uploading a valid IPA and try again. With performing step 2 in .yml script

Comment: In the 2 process no need of 3, 4, 5 steps. 


**How to install**?


Step 1. go to xcode and click on `add additional simulators` in the device list.
Step 2. In Devices tab drag your .app file to installed app section. You app will be installed.

Comment: 2. Using build ios

Worked for me on the updated XCode version